# Laravel - How to convert date value of value in a cell on imported excel files

Tags: excel, laravel-9, maatwebsite-excel

I tried to make a function where User could import formatted file such as `.csv` or `.xlsx`.
I make the function using Maatwebsite excel library.

When I tried to insert the data to database, a cell that has value of today date `24/01/2023` is converted to `44950`

My Import model kinda like this

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Event([
        /**
    * Other attributes and columns
    *
    */
        'date' => $row[1],
    ]);
}
```

How to convert those value to `'Y-m-d'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solutions, idk what happened to the excel imported files, but this helps me.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;

public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Event([
        /**
    * Other attributes and columns
    *
    */
        'date' => Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[1]),
    ]);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/1978